# What is the best and current way to move to HTTPS on a large website?

Tags: https, spdy, http2

From watching [HTTPS everywhere on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBhZ6S0PFCY&utm_source=wmx_blog&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=tls_en_post)
they suggest that HTTPS and SPDY combined will be quicker than just serving web pages/assets over HTTP but then since reading [SPDY is Dead. Long Live HTTP/2](https://zoompf.com/blog/2015/02/spdy-dead-long-live-http2) and what with with HTTP2 support being a way off I am in two minds as to whether to move a large site I'm working on to HTTPS entirely as ultimately it will be slower since doing perf comparison tests (the DOM content loaded took twice the time to load). I also just read somewhere that browsers are dropping support for SPDY.

**What is the state of SPDY and should I just wait until HTTP2 until I advocate moving everything to HTTPS everywhere?** Should I accept the performance hit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPDY is definitely dying, now that HTTP/2 is an [official specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540).

Firefox and Chrome already support HTTP/2, and servers start to deploy it instead of SPDY - Google, Twitter, etc. Internet Explorer support will arrive soon with IE 11.

HTTP/2 is definitely [gaining momentum](https://twitter.com/bagder/status/596199726858575872), and the future will be on HTTP/2 and TLS.

You should not *wait* for HTTP/2, because it's already here.

About the performance hit, the usual recommendation is to benchmark, but there is evidence that HTTP/2 over TLS is much better than HTTP/1.1 over TLS, and possibly comparable - if not better - than cleartext HTTP/1.1, depending on the case.

Reasons behind this are a number of optimizations performed by HTTP/2 such as multiplexing, header compression and resource push, that are simply not possible with HTTP/1.1.

See for example the [demo video](https://webtide.com/spdy-push-demo-from-javaone-2012/) (disclaimer, I am a Jetty committer) we gave in 2012 (about Jetty and SPDY at that time, but [HTTP/2 behaves the same](https://webtide.com/http2-push-demo/)), or the [Go language HTTP/2 demo](https://http2.golang.org/gophertiles), or the [Akamai HTTP/2 demo](https://http2.akamai.com/demo).

With Jetty, for example, you can deploy Java webapps on HTTP/2, but also complete PHP websites on HTTP/2. Our own website, https://webtide.com, is WordPress served by Jetty on HTTP/2.

You can move to TLS and HTTP/2 now.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any more info on Internet Explorer support will arrive soon with IE 11, any refs? I assume HTTP2 needs to be enabled on the server? The site is on apache and squid.

Comment: Further, are there any risks? Are there any vulnerabilities like what SPDY had (when used in conjunction with GZIP)? And I would assume it is completely backwards compatible not to break the web, so there is no harm in updating?

Comment: HTTP/2 does not have the same issues that SPDY had using GZIP to compress headers, so you're safe there. HTTP/2 is indeed backward compatible, so you won't notice (if you are accessing Google servers - GMail, YouTube, etc. you are already using HTTP/2 and I bet you did not notice). You can read about IE and HTTP/2 [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/10/08/http-2-the-long-awaited-sequel.aspx). As for apache and squid, you have to check with those project what is their current status with respect to HTTP/2.